# Verification of PL/SQL datatypes definition in BULK INSERT logic in procedure in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, bulkinsert

I have two tables, DUMMY_REK and DUMMY_REK_LOG. I have written a store procedure to do a BULK insert from DUMMY_REK into DUMMY_REK_LOG. The procedure is running fine but I need to add INDEX BY clause with proper datatype. I am getting errors with the current datatypes definition and hence commented out the same in below code. Can anybody advice me on the correct usage of datatypes?

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE BULK_INSERT_REK_LOG 

 as 


   TYPE tA IS TABLE OF DUMMY_REK.ID%TYPE;-- INDEX BY NUMBER;
   TYPE tB IS TABLE OF DUMMY_REK.KEYWORD%TYPE;-- INDEX BY VARCHAR2(256);
   TYPE tC IS TABLE OF DUMMY_REK.CATEGORY%TYPE;-- INDEX BY VARCHAR2(30);
   TYPE tD IS TABLE OF DUMMY_REK.LIST_NAME%TYPE;-- INDEX BY VARCHAR2(30);
   TYPE tE IS TABLE OF DUMMY_REK.EXPIRY_DATE%TYPE;-- INDEX BY DATE;
   TYPE tF IS TABLE OF DUMMY_REK.SUBMITTED_BY%TYPE;-- INDEX BY NUMBER;
   TYPE tG IS TABLE OF DUMMY_REK.SUBMITTER_COMMENTS%TYPE;-- INDEX BY VARCHAR2(4000);
   TYPE tH IS TABLE OF DUMMY_REK.SUBMITTED_TIMESTAMP%TYPE;-- INDEX BY TIMESTAMP(6);   
   TYPE tI IS TABLE OF DUMMY_REK.DECISIONED_BY%TYPE;-- INDEX BY NUMBER;
   TYPE tJ IS TABLE OF DUMMY_REK.DECISIONED_COMMENT%TYPE;-- INDEX BY VARCHAR2(4000);
   TYPE tK IS TABLE OF DUMMY_REK.DECISIONED_TIMESTAMP%TYPE;-- INDEX BY TIMESTAMP(6);
   TYPE tL IS TABLE OF DUMMY_REK.STATUS_ID%TYPE;-- INDEX BY NUMBER;   
   TYPE tM IS TABLE OF DUMMY_REK.LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP%TYPE;-- INDEX BY TIMESTAMP(6);   
   TYPE tN IS TABLE OF DUMMY_REK.IS_DISABLED%TYPE;-- INDEX BY NUMBER;
   TYPE tP IS TABLE OF DUMMY_REK.KEYWORD2%TYPE;-- INDEX BY VARCHAR2(256);   
   TYPE tQ IS TABLE OF DUMMY_REK.ACCOUNT_NUMBER%TYPE;-- INDEX BY NUMBER;  
   TYPE tR IS TABLE OF DUMMY_REK.CUSTOMER_NAME%TYPE;-- INDEX BY VARCHAR2(256);   
   TYPE tS IS TABLE OF DUMMY_REK.TYPE%TYPE;-- INDEX BY NUMBER;  

    i_keyword_id tA;
    i_keyword  tB;
    i_category  tC;
    i_list_name  tD;
    i_expiry_date tE;
    i_submitted_by  tF;
    i_submitter_comments tG;
    i_submittedtimestamp tH;
    i_decisioned_by  tI;
    i_decisioned_comment  tJ;
    i_decisioned_timestamp  tK;
    i_status_id  tL;
    i_last_updated_timestamp  tM;
    i_is_disabled  tN;
    i_keyword2   tP;
    i_account_number  tQ;
    i_customer_name   tR;
    i_type  tS;

BEGIN


  SELECT * BULK COLLECT INTO i_keyword_id,i_keyword,i_category,i_list_name,i_expiry_date,i_submitted_by,i_submitter_comments,i_submittedtimestamp,i_decisioned_by,i_decisioned_comment,i_decisioned_timestamp,i_status_id,i_last_updated_timestamp,i_is_disabled,i_keyword2,i_account_number,i_customer_name,i_type FROM DUMMY_REK;
   FORALL i IN 1 .. 10 
    INSERT INTO DUMMY_REK_LOG(ID,KEYWORD_ID,KEYWORD,CATEGORY,LIST_NAME,EXPIRY_DATE,USERID,COMMENTS,LOGTIMESTAMP,WORKFLOW_ACTION_ID,WORKFLOW_REASON_ID,FROMSTATUS_ID,TOSTATUS_ID,IS_DISABLED,KEYWORD2,ACCOUNT_NUMBER,CUSTOMER_NAME,TYPE)
      VALUES(GET_NEXT_ID('DUMMY_REK_LOG'),i_keyword_id(i),i_keyword(i),i_category(i),i_list_name(i),i_expiry_date(i),i_decisioned_by(i),i_decisioned_comment(i),i_decisioned_timestamp(i),null,null,null,null,0,i_keyword2(i),i_account_number(i),i_customer_name(i),i_type(i));
commit;     

-- Exception Handling
            EXCEPTION
               WHEN OTHERS THEN
                  -- Rollback
           ROLLBACK;
     RAISE;


END BULK_INSERT_REK_LOG;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error alludes:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE BULK_INSERT_REK_LOG 


    DECLARE
```

should be

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE BULK_INSERT_REK_LOG 
AS
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Patrick. I had to do two things. Use AS instead of DECLARE and also comment out INDEX BY DATATYPE from my code and now I am not getting any compilation error. But I need to use index by clause for perfomance retention. Do you have any idea if I am defining datatypes correctly ?

Comment: I  believe you just need to declare your types with INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER: TYPE tA IS TABLE OF DUMMY_REK.ID%TYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;